# c# richtextbox line numbers column

Tags: c#, notepad++, richtextbox, line-numbers

So I have a Windows Form in C# with only 2 rich text boxes.

The main box I use as the text editor and the other box on the left as a line number column. Everything is working fine. I would like to know how to make the line number column rich text box, to not printing the line number if word wrap is enabled and start printing the line number again if enter key is pressed. This should work similar to Notepad++.

```
1 line 1
2 line 2
3 line 3
4 line 4 - This is a word wrap line that carries on and on. This is a 
  word wrap line that carries on and on. word wrap line that carries on
  and on. This is a word wrap line that carries on and on.
5 line 5
6 line 6
```

Here is my code I'm using

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddLineNumbers()
    {
        richTextBox1.Select();
        Point pt = new Point(0, 0);
        int First_Index = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pt);
        int First_Line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(First_Index);
        pt.X = ClientRectangle.Width;
        pt.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;
        int Last_Index = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pt);
        int Last_Line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(Last_Index);
        richTextBox2.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        richTextBox2.Text = "";
        for (int i = First_Line; i <= Last_Line + 1; i++)
        {
            richTextBox2.Text += i + 1 + "\n";
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddLineNumbers();
    }

    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        if (pt.X == 1)
        {
            AddLineNumbers();
        }
    }

    private void richTextBox1_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddLineNumbers();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of trying to parse the actual text, you should store it as virtual memory that you can manipulate. That way ex. a line can be an object and you can simply have that line have actual textual lines, but still act as a single line virtual. I don't know if you understand it, else I will try to break it down in an answer. It's a bit more complicated, but it should give you an idea

Comment: Notepad++ uses [Scintilla](http://scintilla.org). There is a .NET wrapper for Scintilla; consider using it instead of the RichTextBox if you need features like this.

Comment: I can come up with a solution for this but I need to ask what it is you are trying to achieve? Why do you need 2 textboxes, why not use 1?

Comment: Hi CodingYoshi, I'm a noob so I used 2 rtb's as it was easier. If you have a good and easy solution using only 1 rtb, then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: You could also take a look at this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting